# using Xcode 4 with previous version of xcode's project files

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm about to download Xcode 4 and was wondering, will project files from the recent version of Xcode work with the new version?

Comment: Would Apple really break compatibility for all developers?

Comment: @tc. I wouldn't put it past them.

Comment: @Richard: I doubt they'd completely break the upgrade path, though they might not have a downgrade path. That said, Xcode 4 seems to forget all your settings, and the iTunes-like UI redesign is generally terrible (I still can't figure out how to add a build configuration). I'm quite tempted to downgrade...

Comment: Xcode 4 was the worst mistake so far IMHO.

Comment: Apple claim its fully reversible, and you can move freely between 4 and 3, just make sure you move your old version somewhere safe first (i.e. rename your old "developer" directory to "Xcode 3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opened and saved files without any problem between 3.2.5 and xCode 4. I heard that some had problems with interface builder generated files though. But I think you can say that you are safe if you're not using IB.

Comment: That's the Eiffel tower of if's.

Comment: Hehe, its a big "IF" I agree. But to clear things out. I moved 5 projects from xCode 3.x and I haven't had any problems yet.